# retrieve splistcolumn from xml format and bind it to labels and textbox fields in sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, csom, jsom, elements-xml

Am having a string which stores the values as xml format,i need to parse it and extract values from nodes and bind it with textboxes.
My env. is SP 2013 and i am using JSOM/CSOM to read/insert values from the SPList.
am able to insert into the splist column- a single line of text- as a xml format.
But i am not able to retrieve this xml format back for the purpose of binding with textboxes and labels.

any idea how to achieve this ?
this is the splistcolumn am able to retrieve from the splist, through CSOM

```
               var mystring=

      "<?xml version="1.0"?>
        <catalog>
        <book id="bk101">
     <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
     <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
       with XML.</description>
    </book>
     <book id="bk102">
       <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
           <title>Midnight Rain</title>
           <genre>Fantasy</genre>
           <price>5.95</price>
           <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
         <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
          an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
           of the world.</description>
          </book>
       </catalog>"
```

Am stuck with , how to extract these values of nodes/elements through javascript/jquery or any other client side libraries such that, i can bind these in my UI form fields.

Answer (score 2):

If you are having a xml text then use $.parseXML() to parse it to a xml object then use find() to locate the element.

```
var mystring=

  "<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <catalog>
    <book id="bk101">
 <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
 <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
  <genre>Computer</genre>
  <price>44.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
  <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
   with XML.</description>
</book>
 <book id="bk102">
   <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
       <title>Midnight Rain</title>
       <genre>Fantasy</genre>
       <price>5.95</price>
       <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
     <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
       of the world.</description>
      </book>
   </catalog>"

var xml = $.parseXML(mystring);
console.log($(xml).find('Author').text())
```

to travarse through attribute of a particular node you can use the node directly like mentioned below:

```
$(xml).find('book').each(function() {
$.each(this.attributes, function(i, attrib){
 var name = attrib.title;
 var value = attrib.genre;

});
});
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. but my xml contains multiple elements and how can i iterate through each and every indvidual <book> element.

Comment: you can use that node direclty like : $(xml).find('book').each(function() {
  $.each(this.attributes, function(i, attrib){
     var name = attrib.title;
     var value = attrib.genre;    
  });
});

Comment: Please find the edited answer above